# Check if IF ELSE statement is valid

Tags: c, if-statement

I've been going through and trying to make sense of C code written for a Z80 micro controller. The coder was self taught and unfortunately the code lacks style and thus readability. Apart from the code being full of goto statements it is also very messy with spacing and alignment all over the place.

I have come to a few IF ELSE statement as follows:

```
if(value1==1){
  code();        
}        
else 
if(value2==1) {
  othercode();
}
```

is this the same as:

1.

```
if(value1==1){
  code();        
}        
else if(value2==1) {
  othercode();
}
```

or

2.

```
if(value1==1){
  code();        
 }        
if(value2==1) {
  othercode();
}
```

So before I commit to changing all the code I though best to check.

Comment: How could it be equivalen to the second code? The second code doesn't have `else`.

Comment: Do you think spacing matters in C? It doesn't.

Comment: If the code isn't readable, use a reformatter to neaten it up. Most IDEs will do this for you.

Comment: You can check this yourself, really: compile with `gcc src_file.c -O0 -S -o assembly1.s` and use `vimdiff` to see if the generated assembly is different... also consider using various optimization levels (`-O0` or `-O3`)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Just as I expected, the parser just does not care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code 1  is exactly the same as original code. You just changed the indentation.

Code 2 will behave differently than original code.

Code 1 means if `value1 == 1` is true, execute `code()` else check if `value2 == 1` is true, then execute `othercode()`.

**While**

Code 2 means if `value1 == 1` is true, execute `code()` and now check if `value2 == 1` is true, then execute `othercode()`.

So in a nutshell, in first case `else` condition won't be checked if `if` block evaluates to true. In second case, both `if`s will be checked in all the cases.

Comment: Chosen this answer as it highlights the imprecise example code.

Answer (score 2):

The first two are same:

```
else 
if(value2==1) {
  othercode();
}
```

is same as:

```
else if(value2==1) {
  othercode();
}
```

This is different:

```
if(value1==1){
  code();        
 }        
if(value2==1) {
  othercode();
}
```

In the first two cases the control will not go to the `else`, in case `if` condition is satisfied. But in the last case it will always check both `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is equivalent to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(value1==1){
  code();        
}        
else if(value2==1) {
  othercode();
}
```

this is similar to the code you have given

```
if(value1==1){
  code();        
}
```

`else`// this else will check for one statement , now as the next state is `if`,  so its similar  to `else if`

```
  if(value2==1) {
      othercode();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code 1 is exactly the same as the original code.